# vi: How to change inside 1) the set mark and 2) the current cursor

Tags: vim, vi

What is the shortest way that one can **1)** set a mark (`m<some_char>`), **2)** move the cursor to arbitrary position, and change between **1)** and **2)**?

Is there an equivalent `ciw`, `ci'`, etc. for the above?

(Using vim 8.1.3741, but would appreciate vi-only solution even more.)

Comment: can you explain in detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `ciw`, `ci'`, etc. as individual commands to memorize independently from each other is a trap lots of Vim users fall into, especially if they skip the user manual.

Case in point, `ciw` and `ci'` are not things of their own; they are nothing more than an operator: `c` (`:help c`), followed by a motion: `iw` (`:help iw`) or `i'` (`:help i'`).

What you really are after is not "How to change from X to Y?" but "What motion to use to move to Y?".

Now that you have placed a mark somewhere in your buffer, all you need to do is `c`, followed by the motion to that mark:

```
ma
<move around>
c`aI learned something today.<Esc>
```

Which, of course, works with every other operator.

Comment: If what the po asking is jumping around, why not use Ctrl -o and Ctrl -i?

Comment: @wuhoyt, because `<C-o>` and `<C-i>` have nothing to do with what OP is trying to do. I made the wording less ambiguous.

Comment: still it is not very clear what the po is asking, since you do help to clarify it and I think I am not the only one got confused, I think it is ok to say that the question is not very clear and "constructive" , haha

Comment: Well, that was very clear to me.

Comment: then good for you

Comment: And for OP who got an answer.